# IntelliJ 13: How do I restore the tool window menu bars?

Tags: intellij-idea

I upgraded to IntelliJ 13 from 12 recently.  The tool window menu bars have disappeared.

How can I restore them?  They are useful, because they serve as a reminder about the shortcut keys for each, e.g., 1-Project -> `Alt+1`, 6-TODO -> `Alt+6`, etc.

Here is a screenshot from IntelliJ 12:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At the bottom left, click the rectangle to make those visible. See the image:

[image: image displaying bottom left corner of IDEA]

Comment: Outstanding!  I updated the image to include a red arrow to the tiny icon to click.

Comment: @kunal any idea how to restore the VCS toolbar...with the up and down arrows for pulling an pushing to the repo...in the 2017.2 version of Intellij it just disappeared and I cannot restore it.